# Small (1cm) colored bar from top to bottom on left side of document title page?

Tags: graphics, color

How can I add a small (1cm) colored bar from top to bottom on the left side of my document title page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,color,picture}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(0,-\paperheight){{\color{red}\rule{1cm}{\paperheight}}}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Consult the documentation of **atbegshi** for other examples.

Comment: Tnx, instant succes.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,picture,calc}
\title{foobar}
\author{foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\picture(0,0)\put(-2\oddsidemargin,-\textheight-3.8cm){\color{red!40}\rule{1cm}{\paperheight}}\endpicture
\begin{center}
\huge Me, I and myself

\vspace{3cm}
\normalsize by\\[1cm]
\Large Erasmus von Rotterdam
\vfill
\rule{\linewidth}{5mm}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]